# Gráficos no PrimeFaces

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um método que faz uma consulta no banco e me retorna uma `List`, nessa `List` tenho três dados que me interessam: `Funcionário` e `StatusTarefa`.

Exemplo: Tenho 2 Funcionários realizando várias tarefas, uma tarefa pode ter dois status, `Finalizado` e `Pausado`. Gostaria de exibir em um gráfico a quantidade de tarefas Finalizadas e Pausadas por funcionário. Porém tenho uma dúvida, creio que pra isso precisaria usar uma operação para agrupar e contar os status. Como eu faço isso?

Imagem que exemplifica como quero deixar o gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo esse gráfico com dados fixos:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class GraficoBarraBean {
    private BarChartModel barModel;



    public void init() {
        this.barModel = new BarChartModel();
        createBarModels();
    }

    public BarChartModel getBarModel() {
        return barModel;
    }



    private BarChartModel initBarModel() {
        BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();

        ChartSeries finalizado = new ChartSeries();
        finalizado.setLabel("Finalizado");
        finalizado.set("Diego", 6);
        finalizado.set("Lucas", 10);
        finalizado.set("Cris", 12);


        ChartSeries pausado = new ChartSeries();
        pausado.setLabel("Pausado");
        pausado.set("Diego", 2);
        pausado.set("Lucas", 1);
        pausado.set("Cris", 7);



        model.addSeries(finalizado);
        model.addSeries(pausado);
        model.setAnimate(true);


        return model;
    }

    private void createBarModels() {
        createBarModel();
    }

    private void createBarModel() {
        barModel = initBarModel();

        barModel.setTitle("Tarefas");
        barModel.setLegendPosition("ne");


        Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
        xAxis.setLabel("Funcionários");


        Axis yAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
        yAxis.setLabel("Tarefas");
        yAxis.setMin(0);
        yAxis.setMax(20);
    }

    //Método que faz a consulta no banco e atribui os dados a uma lista de Tarefas
    public List<Tarefa> listarTodos() {
        List<Tarefa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
            lista = tarefaDAO.listar();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar tarefas: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        return lista;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente algo assim com `Map`, dessa forma terá a quantidade para cada funcionário de tarefas pausadas e finalizadas:

```
Map<Funcionario, Integer> tarefasPausadas = new HashMap<Funcionario, Integer>();
Map<Funcionario, Integer> tarefasFinalizadas = new HashMap<Funcionario, Integer>();


        for (Tarefa tarefa : listaTarefa) {
            Funcionario f = tarefa.getFuncionario();
            if (tarefa.getStatusTarefa() == Tarefa.StatusTarefa.Finalizado) {

                if (tarefasFinalizadas.containsKey(f)) {
                    tarefasFinalizadas.put(f, tarefasFinalizadas.get(f) + 1);
                } else {
                    tarefasFinalizadas.put(f, 1);
                }

            } else if (tarefa.getStatusTarefa() == Tarefa.StatusTarefa.Pausada) {
                if (tarefasPausadas.containsKey(f)) {
                    tarefasPausadas.put(f, tarefasPausadas.get(f) + 1);
                } else {
                    tarefasPausadas.put(f, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Assim, ao perguntar para o Funcionário X a quantidade de tarefas finalizadas (ou pausadas) basta fazer:

```
Integer qt=  tarefasFinalizadas.get(f);//se null é porque o funcionário não tem tarefa finalizada.
```

Comment: Opa. Fiz uns testes e o map ta retornando os dados certos, agora vou tentar colocar no gráfico

Comment: Por exemplo no meu model do grafico tenho que passar dois parametros, o segundo eu coloco `tarefasFinalizadas.get(f)` que é a quantidade e no primeiro que é o nome do Funcionário coloco `tarefa.getNome()`?

Comment: Esta assim até agora: `finalizado.setLabel("Finalizado");
  finalizado.set("Diego", tarefasFinalizadas.get(f));`

Comment: Você pode usar o `f.getNome()` já que o f é seu funcionário, se fizer `tarefa.getNome()` virá o nome da tarefa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver o problema. Agora vou estudar um pouco mais sobre HashMap

Comment: Opa. Aqui tem um bom artigo: [HashMap Java: Trabalhando com Listas key-value](http://www.devmedia.com.br/hashmap-java-trabalhando-com-listas-key-value/29811)

Answer (score 2):

@Techies, creio que com isso você vai saber quantos status de cada você tem:

```
private int contadorFinalizado = 0;
private int contadorPausado = 0;

public void contarLista() {
    for (Tarefa tarefa : listaTarefa) {
        if (tarefa.StatusTarefa == tarefa.StatusTarefa.Finalizado) {
            contadorFinalizado++;
        } else {
            contadorPausado++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas como ligo esse contador ao meu funcionario?

Comment: seu funcionário tem uma lista de tarefas?

Comment: Na verdade a lista de tarefas tem um funcionário.

Comment: cada tarefa tem um funcionário ou uma lista deles?

Comment: cada tarefa tem um funcionário e um funcionário pode ter muitas tarefas

Comment: De que tipo é a List, tarefa ou funcionário? Porque você falou 'nessa List tenho três dados que me interessam: Funcionário e StatusTarefa.' você falou três mas mostrou 2 só.

Comment: Digitei errado, são apenas 2 mesmos. Editei a pergunta com uma imagem de como quero deixar e o código que estou fazendo até agora

Comment: A quantidade de cada status e o status podem ser considerados um mesmo item

Comment: Sei que tenho que fazer um for e a cada repetição pegar o funcionário e a quantidade de tarefas, porém como atribuir a quantidade ao funcionário certo?

Comment: Se cada tarefa tem um funcionário e você tem a lista de tarefas, e ainda quer agrupar por funcionário use um hashmap então

Comment: Teria algum exemplo de HashMap?

Comment: @Techies, postei a resposta uma resposta ali dê uma olhada.